# Can't change crop type in django userena mugshot

Tags: python, django

When I upload a mugshot image to the userena profile with whitespace on the edges it gets cropped. It really looks like what 'autocrop' seems to do in easy thumbnails (which userena uses through ThumbnailerImageField as the mugshot field in the UserenaBaseProfile in models) as described in the doc (http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/#thumbnail-options). And I would like to set it to False but can't seem to see how to pass this as it needs to be passed to 'resize_source' to the ThumbnailerImageField as shown here https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails/blob/master/easy_thumbnails/fields.py but in UserenaBaseProfile I can only pass two options via Django settings: size and crop type.
Did I miss something or is there really no way to set more than these settings?

update: I have tried to use the same options through userena and directly using a ThumbnailerImageField in the model (without using autocrop). With the crop set to smart it actually removes the whitespace in both cases. But with the crop set to scale in the ThumbnailerImageField it stops removing the whitespace but setting it to scale in userena does not have the same effect, it keeps removing the whitespace. I also tried with autocrop = False in the ThumbnailerImageField and the results are the same as before so I guess this is not what I want to change. Actually I want to set the crop to something like scale but it has no effect on userena, only on ThumbnailerImageField directly. So I changed the title of the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had userena v 1.0.1 installed and for some reason in the source crop type was hard coded to 'smart' so the settings had no effect. Updating to the latest version solved it.